# How to mount an ISO (or NRG) image and rip it as if it were a physical CD?

Tags: iso, mp3

I have an ISO (created from an NRG with `nrg2iso`) backup of a beloved game from my youth: Dark Reign: Rise of the Shadowhand (1998). I with to relive those better times by listening to game's soundtrack.

Is there a way for me to mount said ISO in such a way that I can rip the audio tracks into mp3 files? I ask because although I can successfully mount the ISO, ripit / abcde report no cd inserted.

How I mounted the ISO:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop iso.iso /media/ISO
```

Alternatively is there another way to recover audio from ISO / NRG images?

**Update:**

I was able to mount the NRG version of my backup in a way that `ripit` recognized using `gCDEmu`. `ripit` failed to rip, however, barfing on the first track - which is most definitely a data track.  Is there a way to make `ripit` ignore the first track?

Comment: How do you "successfully mount the ISO"? What steps do you take to mount it? Also, have you tried the Sound Juicer (package name `sound-juicer` -- you also need `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` package to rip as mp3)?

Comment: He @medigeek, I've updated my question with details on how I mounted the iso. I haven't tried `sound-juicer`, looking at it now.

Comment: I see `sound-juicer` is a GUI app - I'm restricted to CLI currently.

Comment: `sound-juicer` failed, even when the NRG was mounted with `gCDEmu`

Comment: Are you able to play the mounted music cd at all? Is it a Mixed cd? Try converting the nrg format to iso first, using a windows program like ultraiso (you need windows). Also, I don't understand, you mentioned you managed to make it work using gcdemu which is a gtk application if I'm not mistaken and you ask for a client app -- did you mean cdemu the client program? Why do you need cli only anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo mount -o loop ~/iso.iso /media/cdrom0
```

Then try `ripit --device /media/cdrom0`

Comment: Thanks for this - ripit still asks me to insert an audio CD: `Please insert an audio CD!`

Comment: I was able to mount it in a way that `ripit` recognized with `gCDEmu`, but ripping failed. I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are mounting it correctly. You actually shouldn't need to "rip" the cd, and it will probably fail anyway, since it is a data CD. There should be .wav or .mp3 files on the cd. Just look for them after mounting. If they are .wav's you can use the following to easily convert them to mp3s.

```
lame -V2 input.wav output.mp3
```

More info can be found with:

```
lame --help
```

If it is a hybrid cd, as izx mentioned, then you can simply skip the first track with ripit, like this:

```
ripit --device /media/cdrom 2-
```

This will rip track 2+.

Comment: This is incorrect. There was a time when some games used to come with the soundtrack on a "hybrid data/audio" CD -- mid-1990s? To provide high quality sound. Track 1 was data, IIRC. One I can vividly remember is "Monster Truck Madness" (c. 1996).

Comment: The backup iso I have is `Dark Reign: Rise of the Shadowhand`, released 1998. I desire to feel the gentle caress of its glorious soundtrack once more. The nrg/iso files I have (iso created by `nrg2iso`) are ~540 MB, only ~200 MB of data on it when viewed in terminal / nautilus.